# Drupal 8: custom build iFrame in custom block not showing

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In D8, I have created a block programmatically and created an iFrame based on database value. The code is below for the block:

```
class GooglemapBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $build = [];
    //$build['googlemap_block']['#markup'] = 'Implement GooglemapBlock.';
    $config = \Drupal::config('custom.default');
    $build['googlemap_block']['#markup'] = drupal_set_message($config->get('google_token'));
    $rawTxt = $build['googlemap_block']['#markup']['status'][0];
    $build['googlemap_block']['#markup'] = '<iframe src="'.$rawTxt.'" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"allowfullscreen></iframe>';

    return $build;
  }

}
```

I have then assigned the block into the footer_first region from admin panel.

Now, in the `page.html.twig`, I used the same as `{{ page.footer_first }}` , however, I see it shows a blank space. No iFrame is showing.

The stored database value which I want to pass within the iFrame is below:

`https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d9207.358598888495!2d-85.64847801496286!3d30.183918972289003!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0000000000000000%3A0x2320479d70eb6202!2sDillard!5e0!3m2!1sbn!2sbd!4v1462359735720`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246151/iframe-not-displayed-in-drupal-8-controller-page, I did the following in my custom block and it works fine now:

```
class GooglemapBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $build = [];
    //$build['googlemap_block']['#markup'] = 'Implement GooglemapBlock.';
    $config = \Drupal::config('custom.default');
    $build['googlemap_block']['#markup'] = drupal_set_message($config->get('google_token'));
    $rawTxt = $build['googlemap_block']['#markup']['status'][0];

    $iframe = [];
    $iframe = array(
      '#type' => 'inline_template',
      '#template' => '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="'.$rawTxt.'" 
       frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
      //'#context' => ['url' => 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/yAoLSRbwxL8',],
    );

    return $iframe;
  }

}
```